# EXCEL: using a function that returns a value if a group of columns is populated or not

Tags: html, excel

Im using excel, and Im trying to figure out a function that will return a year based on any of the corresponding cells being occupied or not. For instance, I usually put an 'x' in a cell of the corresponding date column and I want to track my attendees first year visiting.

I attempted using an 'isblank' but I havent figured out how to make it cover a span of cells in the same row. I also tried to use a nested If function, but I see that getting out of hand very quickly if I need to make it cover each cell.

What would be the easiest function that I will be able to add additional years to?

[image]

Comment: Try using the `COUNTA` [function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509)

Comment: Thank you, I never knew about the counta function, it work when I nested it with an IF

`=IF(COUNTA(x,J11:S11)>=2, "2017", IF(COUNTA(x,T11:AD11)>=2, "2018", IF(COUNTA(x,T11:AD11)>=2, "2019", "")))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this will work if only one 'x' in range of years

A1:A3 = contains x  # once in range
B1:B3=  years       #range of years

Then the following formula will return year

{=SUM(-((1*ISBLANK(A1:A3))-1)*B1:B3)}

Comment: ok, this helped me a lot! I never knew about the counta,I used it as a nested if function.
`=IF(COUNTA(x,J11:S11)>=2, "2017", IF(COUNTA(x,T11:AD11)>=2, "2018", IF(COUNTA(x,T11:AD11)>=2, "2019", "")))`

Answer (score 0):

Without an array formula, in A2 and copied down to suit:

```
=YEAR(INDEX(B$1:Z$1,MATCH("x",B2:Z2,0)))
```

ColumnZ may be extended to suit. Relies on MATCH returning only the first instance found.

**Assumes** `Year started` is in A1.